# Porting a MySQL app to MongoDB and accommodating the _id field

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, schema-design

I have a PHP app which can hook into multiple backends (currently MySQL or XML) and which I'm trying to make work with MongoDB as well.  One seemingly minor issue that I'm distinctly struggling with is that Mongo mandates '_id' is the name of the primary key.  The backends are generally fairly well abstracted by the application, but the application does need to work with the id on a fairly regular basis, so I access it with code like `$result['id']`, which up until now has abstracted well.

But now I'm faced with trying to (efficiently!) handle a DB that won't let me use 'id' as its primary key, and I'm not sure what the best option is.  Here's what I've thought of so far:

1. Just leave Mongo's '_id' value alone, and set an application variable `$id` to `"id"` or `"_id"` depending on the backend.  Applications should use `$id` to access the ID field, rather than the hard coded `"id"`.  Note that all other fields are accessed by their string names, such as `$result['user']` and so this would be breaking with norms in the application.

   Pros: allows MongoCursor objects to be returned directly when possible, ensuring minimal memory usage and fast access to the data.

   Cons: not backwards-compatible, would require (a fairly tedious) refactoring of any code using this application.
2. Wrap the returned MongoCursor objects in a new iterator class that returns each item with `"_id"` mapped to `"id"` appropriately.  The application would map inbound calls to `"id"` back to `"_id"` when communicating with Mongo.

   Pros: Retains most of the memory efficiency of 1. while preventing most backwards-compatibility issues.

   Cons: Not totally sure how to implement such an object, not convinced it could be done cleanly, or that it would actually work as well as I'm imagining.  To do it right, I'd want to implement similar iterator wrappers for the other backends as well.
3. Load results into memory with `iterator_to_array()` as described in [`MongoCollection.find()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php), do appropriate transforms, and return the array.

   Pros: conceptually simpler than 2., would work well with the rest of my app.

   Cons: obviously a poor choice in terms of memory.  Not the end of the world given the app, but still not ideal.

Do any of these options stand out as particular reasonable and robust solutions to this issue?  Can anyone suggest other alternatives for handling primary keys in a backend-agnostic way?  Additional backends are a possibility in the future, so issues or benefits of a given method related to other data storage systems are also welcome.

I'm currently leaning towards 2., but I welcome your thoughts.

Comment: You could ignore _id entirely, use "id" in the MongoDB documents as well and simply add an {id:1} index. The only downside I can think of is the unused _id index. "id" is not an invalid field name in MongoDB.

Comment: It just seems inefficient and a poor implementation to exactly duplicate the behavior of `_id`.  I suppose it's not really that bad, just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Well. "Right" went out of the window when you tried to abstract multiple storage solutions kind sir ;). Since different storage solutions have different functional sweetspots you'll always end up using them in a suboptimal way. I agree it's not perfect though but it's a better, more efficient solution than the three you proposed.

Comment: That's certainly fair :P I would say the primary goal is to maintain proper usage of the underlying data store, such that should the abstraction ever become unacceptable, the data is intact, and stored in a robust way.  A duplicate column and index doesn't seem like a good choice given that goal, though I agree it would be easiest from the abstraction point of view.

Comment: I see, well in that case 2) is probably the best way to go. I do something similar in our in-house mapping tool.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just overloading the _id column? I've done this a handful of times and even in some of the Mongo Examples when working with data sets this can be performed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with option 2, wrapping the iterator and hiding the existing '_id' field.  Not clean, and not elegant, but the best I could do with what I had.  Working on this really made me pine for Python.